# mount efs from different vpc in different account using transit gateway using dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount to a shared efs in one account's vpc with another ec2(s) in another account's vpc.

I have a transit gateway set up with the relevant routing in place.

I am trying to mount with dns , the efs dns is only resolvable in the account where it resides and I am trying to steer away from using IPs because the ec2s can be in different in availabilty zones.

Is there any way to resolve the dns with a single dns entry that will resolve to the mount target in the correct availability zone ?

Authorizing hosted zones between is not an issue , I am just struggling to find a clean way of doing this . I've thought of trying efs-a.example.com and it's respective az mount target ip . But I'd still like something that can be like efs.example.com to resolve the respective azs efs ip.

Is using IPs the only way to mount correctly based on azs besides the solution the above yet similar solution ?